# Is there a better/different way to have inline html elements on the same line without having to actually have the coded elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: Thank you for the feedback on how to properly post :) Much appreciated!

So I am doing freeCodeCamp's 'Responsive Web Design' course and am at the section in which I need to position paragraph elements on the same line to have the site look a certain way

```
      <article class="item">
        <p class="flavor">French Vanilla</p><p class="price">3.00</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
        <p class="flavor">Caramel Macchiato</p><p class="price">3.75</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
        <p class="flavor">Pumpkin Spice</p><p class="price">3.50</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
        <p class="flavor">Hazelnut</p><p class="price">4.00</p>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
        <p class="flavor">Mocha</p><p class="price">4.50</p>
      </article>
```

Now I don't like how that looks with both elements on the same line and I also use prettier for VS Code which I have set to Format on save. This automatically makes it so that I can't have those elements on the same line anyway (which I have no problem with visually)but it  changes how the design of the web page looks.

This is how it is supposed to look when doing it the way they want (with elements on the same line)[Picture of the target webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joe5z.png)

This is how mine looks on VS Code when I have the parapgraph elements one above the other[Picture of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DvX8.png)

So obviously this isn't how it's supposed to be. My question is: how can I get the name and prices on the same line with the correct spacing without having to put the paragraph elements on the same line of code.

My full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cafe Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <main>
        <h1>CAMPER CAFE</h1>
        <p>Est. 2020</p>
        <section>
          <h2>Coffee</h2>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">French Vanilla</p>
            <p class="price">3.00</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Caramel Macchiato</p>
            <p class="price">3.75</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Pumpkin Spice</p>
            <p class="price">3.50</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Hazelnut</p>
            <p class="price">4.00</p>
          </article>
          <article class="item">
            <p class="flavor">Mocha</p>
            <p class="price">4.50</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My full css file for the project:

```
h1,
h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/curriculum/css-cafe/beans.jpg);
}
.menu {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
.flavor {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
}
.price {
  text-align: right;
  width: 25%;
}
.item p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

My vs code settings json:

```
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Hack Nerd Font",
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hack Nerd Font",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "SynthWave '84",
  "synthwave84.brightness": 2,
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
  "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell (x86)",
  "eslint.notebooks.rules.customizations": [],
  "prettier.printWidth": 250,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true
}
```

I have tried to change prettier's printWidth to 250 to allow me to have the elements on the same line (which I couldn't actually get to work and had to end up disabling prettier for HTML. Then I decided actually I don't want to have to have the elements on the same line and changed my prettier settings back and re-enabled it for HTML because I really like the way it looks like this (is that stupid?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: That's much better, thank you for editing  I would take a look at `flex` (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox, etc.); it should be pretty easy to make `.item` a `display: flex`, and arrange the two `<p>` elements so `flavour` is at the start, and `price` is at the end. I'm not an expert on CSS, so I'm not sure what's up with your current code, but alignment and width %s doesn't seem like the correct approach, especially if you're looking for a responsive layout.

Comment: Sidenote, placement of the HTML elements in your code doesn't matter when rendering; if you have `<p>...</p><p>...</p>` (like your 1st example), they will render the same as `<p>...</p>\n<p>...</p>` (`\n` being a new line like in your 2nd example), but generally one element per line is recommended for readability. Exceptions are stuff like Tables and Lists, which I've seen written as `<th><a>...</a></th>`,  or `<li><span>...</span></li>`, etc., but it's ultimately up to you to decide on your coding styling.